# Using SSL in EJB got Exception: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, exception, ssl, glassfish, ejb

I have followed the instruction in [Oracle Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/Security6.html#wp148434) to create new "keystore.jks" and "cacerts.jks" files with new password (not using the default "changeit"). To be more precise, I used the following 3 commands to generate the files:

```
1. keytool -genkey -alias s1as -keyalg RSA -keypass newpass -storepass newpass -keystore keystore.jks
2. keytool -export -alias s1as -storepass newpass -file server.cer -keystore keystore.jks
3. keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias s1as -file server.cer -keystore cacerts.jks -keypass newpass -storepass newpass
```

After I copy the new "keystore.jks" and "cacerts.jks" files into "/domains/domain1/config" folder and start the App server, I ran into the following exception:

```
IllegalStateException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

However, I think the password should be correct because when I was configuring GlassFish to use the new files, I did add this line to the JVM options:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=newpass
```

I tried to compare the old "keystore.jks" file with the new one using the command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks
```

I noticed that in the result for the old file, other than the s1as certificate's information, it also contains the following line:

```
Extensions:
#1 ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 1B 31 49 23 1C 5B 17 1D    9F 02 86 FD F7 2B 44 F4   .1I#.[.........+D.
0010: 1B E3 7A C6
]
]
```

The result for the new file doesn't contain anything similar to the above lines. In my app, I intend to use self-signed certificate. I'd be very grateful if someone could give me some advice on how to tackle this problem.

Best regards,

James Tran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this parameter `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=newpass`